# Left join in Entity Framework with multiple join operations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, left-join

I am working with LINQ entities and didnt find any good solution for this. I have a big query which gives me the records according to that and here is the query and this query doesnt give me the expected result when joining with SMSLog table due to some of the shortlinks are null on callback side so I have to make it outer but is it easier to change whole query or is there anyway to achieve outer join in this particular situation

```
var callback = Context.Callbacks.Where(_ => _.Status == 1)
                .Join(Context.Users,
                    c => c.UserId,
                    u => u.Id,
                    (c, u) => new
                    {
                        User = new
                        {
                            u.SalesRepId,
                            UserName = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName,
                            u.Email,
                            u.PhoneNumber,
                        },
                        Callback = new
                        {
                            c.TaskId,
                            c.DateCallback,
                            c.DeviceId,
                            c.DateEnd,
                            c.callbackId,
                            c.Point,
                            c.DeviceType,
                            c.Code,
                            c.ShortLinkCode
                        }
                    })
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Join(Context.SMSLog,
                    c => c.Callback.ShortLinkCode,
                    sms => sms.ShortLinkCode,
                    (c, sms) => new
                    {
                        c.Callback,
                        c.User,
                        SMS = new
                        {
                            sms.TelNo
                        }
                    })
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Concat(query)
                .Join(Context.Items,
                    c => c.Callback.TaskId,
                    i => i.Id,
                    (c, i) => new
                    {
                        c.Callback,
                        c.User,
                        c.SMS,
                        Item = new
                        {
                            i.en_US,
                            i.ru_RU,
                            i.tr_TR,
                        },
                    })
                .AsEnumerable();
```

I have tried this query to concat them but this didnt work out for me

```
var query = (from cb in Context.Callbacks
                         join usr in Context.Users on cb.UserId equals user.Id
                         join sms in Context.SMSLog on cb.ShortLinkCode equals sms.ShortLinkCode into gj
                         where cb.Status == 1
                         from subcallback in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new
                         {
                             Callback = new
                             {
                                 cb.TaskId,
                                 cb.DateCallback,
                                 cb.DeviceId,
                                 cb.DateEnd,
                                 cb.callbackId,
                                 cb.Point,
                                 cb.DeviceType,
                                 cb.Code,
                                 cb.ShortLinkCode
                             },
                             User = new
                             {
                                 usr.SalesRepId,
                                 UserName = usr.FirstName + " " + usr.LastName,
                                 usr.Email,
                                 usr.PhoneNumber,
                             },
                             SMS = new
                             {
                                 subcallback.TelNo
                             }
                         }).AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: if not exist in ``cb``, you can select ``null`` value, by changing the ``SMS`` to ``SMS = new {subcallback?.TelNo}``

Comment: Hmmmm if I do this to first one before the concat do I still need that because it would be the best to rid of the second query if possible. I am trying this now thanks for the help

Comment: you're welcome, yeah i mean it for the second. the first it's hard to read it.

Comment: Actually cant trying that due to expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operation

Comment: for the left join, if  one value of ``ShortLinkCode`` for sms not exist in cb. the second query, will throw an exception, because ``subcallback`` will be null.